# Show group of checkboxes if a checkbox in the group is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle, show-hide

Please have a look at the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qpgk58bx/).

What I'd like to do is show the checkboxes in the group on page load if any checkbox in the group is prechecked.

here is the HTML:

```
<ul>
<li class="header">
    <h3>Group 1</h3>
</li>
<li class="option">
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Value</label>
</li>
<li class="option">
    <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> Value</label>
</li>
<li class="option">
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Value</label>
</li>
<li class="header">
    <h3>Group 2</h3>
</li>
<li class="option">
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Value</label>
</li>
<li class="option">
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Value</label>
</li>
<li class="option">
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Value</label>
</li>
<li class="header">
    <h3>Group 3</h3>
</li>
<li class="option">
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Value</label>
</li>
<li class="option">
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Value</label>
</li>
<li class="option">
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Value</label>
</li>
</ul>
```

The main obstacle for me is I can't wrap the group (like in a `<div>` or an `<li>`) because the headers are inserted dynamically. It would be great to show/hide the wrap, but that's not an option. I can't figure out how to target the checkboxes in the group if I can't wrap it. Your ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Always post your code in your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use filter function for getting the elements that have checked and the trigger click for its supported head element:

```
$('li.header').click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('li:not(.option)').slideToggle();
    return false;
}).filter(function(){
   return $(this).nextUntil('li:not(.option)').find(':checked').length > 0;
}).click();
```

**### Working Demo**

Comment: That is beautiful! I'm looking at the jQuery API Docs for .filter() now to understand it. Thank you so much. Will make the answer accepted ASAP.